# Prevent Doctrine from fetching related entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `User` entity which has One-To-Many association with `Account` entity:

```php
/**
 * @var Account[]
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *     targetEntity="AppBundle\Account",
 *     mappedBy="user",
 *     cascade={"persist", "remove"},
 *     orphanRemoval=true
 * )
 */
protected $accounts;
```

I'm fetching a list of users and joining accounts to them:

```php
$builder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('U')
    ->from('Model:User', 'U')
    ->leftJoin('U.accounts', 'A')
;
```

However, when I'm trying to access fetched accounts of the user I can see that Doctrine are making additional queries to the database to fetch accounts for each user.

```php
foreach ($users as $user) {
    foreach ($user->getAccounts() as $account) {
        // This triggers additional Doctrine query.
        var_dump($account->getId());
    }
}
```

I'm running this code as a batch job and I want to achieve maximum performance by pre-loading users with accounts and not to issue additional queries later.

**Why Doctrine makes additional queries and how to prevent this?**

I've tried to use `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"` option for `OneToMany` association, but without any luck, the results are the same.

Comment: ->select('U,A')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add the `account` data to the select statement:

```
$builder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('U')
    ->from('Model:User', 'U')
    ->addSelect('A')
    ->leftJoin('U.accounts', 'A')
;
```

Regarding the fetch, `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"` is for loading less data. You probably want `fetch="EAGER"` which will automatically load related entities.

Comment: My god. You are right of course. Looks like one should sleep after all...

Comment: No need for Join::WITH and it would be better of you either showed the entire query or showed the portion that needed changing using the names from the original query.

Comment: Any good soul to share a link to the opposite question: when I have the fetch=EAGER already annotated on original entity, but in some cases I do NOT want that, but simple lazy load? I can't find it, everyone's tlking about getting the EAGER working :(